# In Nitrous.io, Is there a way to input stuff for the console in iOS?

Tags: nitrousio

The keyboard won't show up for console, and it is only for the editor. Is it possible there is some workaround about this? It is so close to fully support iOS!

Even better if nitrous.io guy can address this issue...

Answer (score 1):

iOS is not officially supported so your mileage may vary when using an iPad, iPhone as well as other mobile devices.

Full iOS support is in our roadmap, I suggest following [@nitrousio](http://twitter.com/nitrousio) for product announcements.

Comment: Where can we vote up feature requests like this? Myself and a colleague of mine are both extremely interested in this. Even a bluetooth keyboard isn't allowing input into the console (iOS 9 beta 5), so the Nitrous is useless our iPad's for Rails development at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth keyboard works (in Chrome and Safari).  Just tap inside the console area twice, then start typing.

Another option is to install a code editor (like Diet Coda) which provides an SSH console.